# How to save previous "output" or a state of the previous output in a recursive function call in python?

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search, recursive-datastructures

I am using a recursive function to generate text using a RegEx match, where it finds a pattern of words according to a combination of synonyms inside square brackets (`pattern = '\[.*?\]'`) separated by a string separator (I have defined a `SEPARATOR =#lkmkmksdmf###`. )

The initial sentence argument to the function is something like:

`[decreasing#lkmkmksdmf###shrinking#lkmkmksdmf###falling#lkmkmksdmf###contracting#lkmkmksdmf###faltering#lkmkmksdmf###the contraction in] exports of services will drive national economy to a 0.3% real GDP [decline#lkmkmksdmf###decrease#lkmkmksdmf###contraction] in 2023 from an estimated 5.0% [decline#lkmkmksdmf###decrease#lkmkmksdmf###contraction] in 2022`

and

The function reads like:

```
def combinations(self,sentence,master_sentence_list:list):
        pattern = '\[.*?\]'

        if not re.findall(pattern, sentence, flags = re.IGNORECASE):
            if sentence not in sentence_list:
                sentence_list.append(sentence)
        else:
            for regex_match in re.finditer(pattern, sentence, flags = re.IGNORECASE):
                repl=regex_match.group(0)[1:-1]
                start_span = regex_match.span()[0]
                end_span = regex_match.span()[1]
                for word in repl.split(self.SEPARATOR):
                    tmpsentence = (
                        sentence[0: start_span] +
                        word +
                        sentence[end_span:]
                    )
                    new_sentence = deepcopy(tmpsentence)
                    self.combinations(new_sentence,master_sentence_list)
```

Thus, the `master_sentence_list` variable keeps appending the sentences like a DFS tree

I want to avoid using the same words twice - for example if I used the word "decline" then it should not be used again while choosing the next set of words in the inner for loop after the recursive call. Is there a way of "storing" the word used by the words inside the first square bracket when a word from the second square brackets pattern is parsed and so on?

*It is like a DFS tree where each node has to store the state of each of its parent node.
*
How can I modify the function to not use the same words again in a single sentence of the sentence_list?

I tried using an argument called "avoid_words: list" to which would store the list of the parent node words. But how do I erase it when I have to move over to the next word in from the first square bracket (or starts from a different "root")?

Comment: This is just not a regular expression problem.  You're not looking for patterns, you're looking for exact matches on full words.  Just split the text into words using `.split()`, and go through the list one by one.  This is just an abuse of regexes.

Answer (score 3):

As Tim pointed out, if there really is no other way to input the string and it's arguments (which I doubt) you should use `split()` function to separate initial sentence into words (synonyms) and pure sentence.

Bellow is the commented code I would use, have I had to solve a situation like this.

```
def all_combinations(sentence) -> list:
    pattern = r'\[(.*?)\]'
    synonyms = []
    resulting_sentences = []

#Put all of the synonyms into synonyms list
    list_of_synonyms = re.findall(pattern, sentence, flags = re.IGNORECASE)
#Remove synonyms from the origingal sentence
    sentence = re.sub(pattern, '[]', sentence)


#split sinynonyms into dictionaries containing tuple and clock
    for i, x in enumerate(list_of_synonyms):
            synonyms.append(tuple(x.split('#lkmkmksdmf###')))
 
#Create combinations and put those into list of sets. 
# Sets can hold only unique elements, thus in case of duplicity thwy will be shorter.
# The set will be removed if it's length is <3.
    synonym_combinations = list(set(combinations) for combinations in itertools.product(*synonyms) if len(set(combinations)) == 3)

#iterate over combinations
    for combination in synonym_combinations:
#iterate over words in combinations
        formatted_sentence = sentence
        for synonym in combination: formatted_sentence = formatted_sentence.replace('[]',synonym,1)
#append formatted sentence to resulting senteces
        resulting_sentences.append(formatted_sentence)
    return resulting_sentences
```